# What's the probability that in three children 1 is a girl.

Tags: probability

It was asked that what is the probability that only one is a girl in a group of 3 children.

My sample space:- 
B B B 
B B G 
B G G 
G G G

What my friend says:-
B B B 
B B G 
B G B 
G B B 
B G G 
G G B 
G B G 
G G G

He says it will be like the when 3 coins are tossed. But I say that BBG and BGB are same. So there will be only 4 total outcomes.

Am I correct? Because if we see logically, then probability of one girl is 1/4. Because 1 girl is one girl, whether she is at left or right or middle.

And it is different from the 3 coins that we are tossing.

Comment: His three outcomes GBB, BGB, and BBG each have probability 1/8. When you collapse them into a single outcome, these probabilities are added so in your sample space BBG has probability 3/8.

Comment: Hi there, the probability of three girls "GGG" and two girls "GGB" in your case is 1/4 each. But this shouldn't be the case as it would be "considerably" more rare for all three children to be girls than it is for them to be two girls and one boy. In other words what i mean is, even in your case you need to also take the probability of each of those events happening also in the consideration because they are not independent events. The easier way to do this is just by taking the sample set what your friend took. Or weight each event with its own probablity in your case.

Comment: Why wouldn't your reasoning also apply when flipping coins? You say BBG and BGB are the same; one could say that HHT and HTH are the same result, and there are four outcomes for the number of heads.

Comment: because {GBB} is separate from {BBG} and {BGB} , because the position matters, the position depicts the uniqueness of each event, each birth of child in a unique event, and we can understand that in human terms as age for example. Since cases are distinct you must add them distinctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're both correct on the sample space (in a sense); however, in your case, the outcomes are not equally likely.

Think about the order in which the children are born; there are $3$ ways to get two boys and one girl:

- First a boy is born, then another boy, then a girl
- First a boy, then a girl, then a boy
- First a girl, then a boy, then a boy

On the other hand, there is only one order in which three girls arrive, as another example. That is to say, "$2$ boys, $1$ girl" is not as likely as "$3$ girls". And this should make sense: think about your real life, and how often you've seen groups of three siblings, and how rare it's been an entire gender was excluded from them.

Having the sample space written in terms of equally likely events makes it significantly easier to calculate the relevant probabilities. Hence, even if each ordering of events results in the "same" outcome, in some sense, it's usually best to account for order when reasonable anyways.

This comes from a principle which says, if every event involved is equally likely,

$$\text{the probability $X$ happens} = \frac{\text{the number of ways $X$ can happen}}{\text{the number of possible events overall}}$$

Then one easily sees, for instance, the probability of "$2$ boys, $1$ girl" is $3/8$.

Since the events in your sample space are ***not*** equally likely, one has to use a different means of calculation.

---

An example taking your fallacy to the extreme is winning the lottery.

In your eyes, the sample space of events for winning a lottery has two events: "winning" and "losing". But if you try to calculate the probability in the erroneous method you have, you would conclude your probability of winning is $50\%$ (before we've even considered what the lottery is or how many people are in it, too!), which is obviously silly.

Comment: But for example, in a room three children are present. Now a person X is allowed to see them. Case 1: He sees that the first one is a girl and the second and third are boys. Case 2: He sees that the first one is a boy, second is a girl and the third is a boy. In both the cases he is asked to tell how many girls he saw. He would say 1 only, in both the cases. This is what I am trying to tell. And also you said to look at their age, but what if they are trio?

Comment: Even twins and triplets and so on are not necessarily born at the *exact* same time (someone comes out first). If you prefer to think of it differently, think about the positioning of the children in the room, say one in each corner. The child in one corner has a chance to be a girl or a boy, and the same for each of the others. Again, we can impose an ordering of the children in this scenario which shows that each of your claimed outcomes are not equally likely

Comment: In a group of 3 children, there might be that only 1 is a girl, 2 are girls, all 3 are girls or there are no girls. Can't we say it this way?

Comment: In combinatorics, you always need to clearly identify each element. If you roll 3 dice, you need to say 'I roll 3 dice, 1st is blue, 2nd is red, and 3rd is green' ; If you have 3 children, you need to consider : the eldest, the middle one and the youngest. if you flip 3 coins, you need to consider 3 coins of different values or 3 coins of different colors ; If you don't do this, you mix different cases into one, and you obtain false results.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you

Comment: @Congruent Just to chime in: [There are multiple ways of framing a probability experiment](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/19548/372).

Comment: Why did you decide that outcomes of the 2nd sample space are equiprobable? It was not in the question.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. For the reason unknown, it assumes that the outcomes of the second sample space are equiprobable, though the question gives no information about probabilities. A lot of upvotes show that misunderstanding is very common.

Comment: If we use the common-sense assumption that is often implicit in these problems that boys and girls are equiprobable births, then I don't see the issue. (Like, yes, human gender and sex is quite a bit more nuanced than that, and the probabilities dependent on a multitude of factors, but a grade school probability question is not where that nuance is going to arise or particularly worth going over, nor what the student is really being tested on from a pedagogical standpoint.)

Comment: Defining sample space does not define probabilities. I guess the OP was really asking outcomes of which sample space are equiprobable, without giving information to justify answer. I don't see any reason why outcomes of 2nd  sample space are equiprobable and of the 1st are not,

Comment: Because, as explained in my answer, each child has their own (assumingly independent, under the various common-sense assumptions initially proposed) chance to be a boy or a girl, and we are only concerned with a group of three children (unordered). Imposing an order makes each collection of the eight equiprobable and it thus easier to analyze the unordered collections; foregoing order does not. If this answer is unsatisfactory to you, I have no idea how else to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Sample space alone is not enough to calculate probabilities. To begin with, before selecting the sample space, you need to specify probabilistic experiment, and only after that you have information which sample space to select. Note that we did not assign probabilities yet, that will be the next step.

The question may look good in natural language, but it is lacking necessary information to convert it to math problem.